# A way to efficiently and effectively combine papers for musical scores

Tags: paper, technique-selection

I printed out some sheet music and would like to combine the pages. Currently I use tape and I cut the margins out (I need to just rescale the pages). The taping is kind of a pain because if things are not lined up it creates minor problems (it probably would be better to tape one page then lay the next one on the tape, but I am butting them together then taping). Of course both sides need to be taped, but one side is not sticky.

Not sure if there is a machine, device, or product that could be used for this that would work well? I do need it to fold for storage and probably plan on putting them in a binder when not in use. If there was a sort of dual end tape where the middle was not sticky then it would be pretty cool. It wouldn't solve many of the problems but would help with only having to tape one side.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what is the nature of the requirements, or the problems you're encountering.  Could you add an image of what the pages look like that you need to join?  Also, how many pages need to be joined to form a "unit" (pairs of pages vs. more)?

Comment: Is your goal to bind the sheets like a book (all sheets are glued together at the left edge) or do you want to create a folding band of sheets (sheets are glued alternatingly on the left and right edge)? The paragraph about "dual end tape where the middle was not sticky" confuses me. Either I can only find a wrong translation (double sided tape) or I have no idea how exactly the process is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need it to lie flat when open, and don't have access to a printer that will print double size pages (e.g. A3 if you normally use A4). If you do have such a printer it's easy - fold in half and use a long arm stapler or sewing machine in the crease.

A comb binding machine would work well, giving you a book that lies nicely open. You can add, remove, and rearrange pages, and there's no tape. There is a margin needed at the seam though, so if you're joining the pages to get very long lines (which I've never seen in sheet music) this won't work.

Otherwise you can stop the residual exposed surface of tape being sticky by dusting it with talc after you've made the join. This will just brush off the paper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a specific kind of tape like that, and I doubt it exists. Nevertheless, there are a few other options to (temporarily) keep your scores neatly stacked and usable in addition to Chris H's solutions:

- Use a **(double) hole punch**:

  [image]
  <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punch)</sup>

  Align your papers at one of the corners, punch the holes, and tie your papers together using anything you fancy (I recommend screw posts, or, [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_bolt), 'sex bolts' for sturdiness, but if you need to be able to read the music score while playing an instrument, a ribbon or rope might be preferred, as with the slack it offers the papers can easily be turned).
- Use **binder clips**, or a '**bulldog clip**':

  [image][image]
  <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binder_clip)</sup>                                                        <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldog_clip)</sup>

  This option is good for a quick and easy way to keep your papers together. The clips will likely need to be removed when playing from the score.

Comment: See also [this Lifehacks SE thread](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/how-to-hold-together-large-packet-of-paper).

Comment: [Treasury tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasury_tag) are another option if you punch holes